# Find most important inputs of LSTM-RNN for multivariate time series modeling

Tags: neural-network, keras, lstm, rnn

The question is similar to the one asked in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173661/how-to-evaluate-the-importance-of-input-in-lstm), but I think it is more appropriate to be here. It remains anyway unanswered.

> Assuming **multivariate time series**, how to evaluate the importance of
>   all inputs of an **already trained LSTM-RNN**?

Thus, which are the inputs that affect the output the most?

I am aware of Pearson correlation (for linear relations) and Information Gain based on Entropy reduction to explore input/output relations in general, but this is not what I need. How can you infer from an **already trained LSTM** network, which inputs affect the output the most? Can you tell by the weights?

Any suggestion or literature would be welcome.